# script appears to run with no progress

Tags: shell-script, mv, exec

This script is to find a list of files stored in a text file, and if the files are found, copy them to a specific location. So far I have had success running the portions up to but not including the portion that actually copies the files. When I add the code to copy the file, starting with exec, the script no longer appears to work and makes no progress. I would like to understand what is locking this script up and how to make it work correctly. Thanks!

```
#!/bin/bash
#Find files from a list in a file and copy them to a common folder

mapfile -t filelist < filelist.txt

for file in "${filelist[@]}"; do
    xargs find ~ -name '${filelist[@]}' -exec mv -t ~/Document/foundfiles/ {} +;
done
```

Comment: `xargs` (which is superfluous, as far as I can see) is waiting for standard input

Comment: I'll get rid of that, that was from an old iteration. That was apparently masking another problem, thanks.

Comment: ... also presumably it should be `-name "$file"`

Comment: Yes, that has made more progress, thank you!